# Secure Java from reverse-engineering using industry grade encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption, reverse-engineering, bouncycastle

**Objective:**

Secure my Java application from reverse engineering.

**Idea:**

1. split the program into two halves (loader and program)
2. loader will be a regular jar
3. program will be an encrypted jar file (bouncycastle, AES?)
4. loader asks secure server (https) for a key to decode program
5. loader then decodes program and loads up it's classes

**Questions:**

Would number 5 be possible?
Has anyone here done this?
Do you know any library already available?
Can you spot major pitfalls / would you do it differently?

**Extra**

I know it is impossible to prevent full reverse engineering of the code.
I'm just looking to make it harder and more traceable.

Comment: Seems like it should be possible. I don't think it would be too hard to crack it though, just wait for the loader to decrypt the program and save it to disk...

Comment: Reverse engineering the regular jar, decode the program and save it to a class file then reverse engineering again

Comment: @Bwmat, the "program" would be on memory only. Never on disk.

Comment: Or just install an SSL proxy on the system this application is running on so you can see the decryption key as it is received by the loader. Or just look for it in the memory space of the loader. Or just grab the decrypted application from memory once it has been decrypted. I could go on, but you get the idea...

Comment: @Hernán Eche the regular `jar` asks a key to a remote server that would only be served to the "right" machine using IP.

Comment: @jeffsix thanks. Any better solutions (using Java)?

Comment: You cannot prevent reverse engineering of your application. You can only make it more difficult (slow down the process).

Comment: @jeffsix, thks! :) I should have pointed that out earlier. I know there is no definite here. Even the AES can and will be broken. I'm looking for real-world ideas that would be possible to implement and create some trouble (apart from the easy on obfuscation).

Comment: *Carefully* consider the amount of time you dedicate to this task, vs providing new and useful functionality to your customers. *most* customers will pay for a useful product, and not attempt to reverse engineer it (nor switch to a hacked version, so long as you're fair with them)

Comment: Just a thought, perhaps you could load the classes on one machine and them securely dispatch (serialize > encrypt > decrypt > deserialize) them to another machine (mobile agents, an example is the aglet project http://aglets.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there aren't any users. The program should be used by me alone. It's a modeled trading approach. The idea here is to protect (as far as possible) the intellectual property behind the models.

Comment: If you're the only one using this...who are you concerned about reverse engineering it? And how would that person obtain access to it?

Comment: @cyber-monk thks! That's actually a spin of what I was thinking on doing (keeping the source encrypted) vs serving the source from another machine but seams very interesting. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @jeffsix the code will probably run cloud based (and the recent linode hacks got me on alert) or it could eventually be run on a co-location machine for latency issues. Meaning that any number of people could have physical access to the machine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever :) there is one. Me. But it's not for sale nor am I concerned about adding "features" as I'm the only who should be using it. Please read the above comment as to why I'm still worried about preserving the source-code.

Comment: In that case, your time/effort/money is MUCH better spent making sure that appropriate physical access controls to this server are in place (as part of your colo agreement) and that the OS and other logical access points to at are properly locked down, configured, and monitored. The ROI for these steps is so much higher than trying to implement anti-RE within the actual application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very possible using Class Loaders. But it is still very easy to decode your program. All one would need to do is change your Loader to write all the classes to disc before it loads them into memory with your custom ClassLoader.

**Update**

If the Loader is something your users can execute then I would just need to decompile and replace the Loader JAR file to dump the classes to disk. Not only that I am certain there must be something that can take a memory dump of a JVM and output all of the loaded byte code.

If the Loader is on a locked machine in which users cannot obtain access, then what is the Use Case you are trying to solve?

The "solutions" to these problems are:

1. Use an advanced Obfuscator that is designed to break decompilers.
2. Prevent access to the JAR files themselves. Either through ACL's on the machine or by employing a remote server to execute the code you want secure. This is essentially how Web Applications work. There can be a substantial amount of IP or processing that Stackoverflow does but we would never have access to the back-end processing, on the result of the User Experience output.

Comment: do take into account that were you to re-create the loader you would run-it in a different machine that would not be authorized by the remote server. Do you have a better solution (using Java)? Thanks.

Comment: @Frankie Why would it be ran on a different machine? Is your loader on a machine that no one would have access to? If that is the case then why are you worried about decompiling?

Comment: @Frankie Is the machine running the loader somehow limited in functionality?  What's to stop an attacker from making a hacked loader jar and putting it back on the original machine?

Comment: @Andrew Finnell the loader will probably be run on a cloud server to which I'll have root access. The recent linode hacks have put me on alert.

Comment: @Matt C If the machine where the loader runs gets compromised I'm hoping I catch the hack in a short time-frame and can take pro-active measures.

Comment: @Andrew Finnell thanks for the answer. I'm going with a hybrid and updated the question to reflect my final approach to the problem but your answer captures it in quite some detail.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's all completely possible; by defining your own classloader you can use an arbitrarily complex process to generate the classes, which will then be available to be reverse engineered.

The only way to protect an algorithm from reverse engineering is to execute
it remotely, in which case the problem becomes that all the inputs and outputs
of the remotely executed code can't be trusted.